# C# class instance specfic timer elapsed event

Tags: c#, timer

In my program I need to generate an instance of a class which is "Vehicle", the Vehicle class has a timer within it, along with a boolean "vExists", when the timer hits an interval.

```
class VehicalGen
{
    private Random rn1 = new Random();

    private int agrotime;
    private bool vExists;
    //static AgrivationHandler agroTimeHandler;
    private static Timer agroTimer = new Timer(100);

    //agrotime: anywhere between 2 and 4 seconds (2000 to 4000)

    ///Generates the new Vehicles using GetCarType to change the outcome of the later variables
    public VehicalGen()
    {
        this.vtype = RandomGeneration.GetCarType(rn1);
        switch (this.vtype)
        {
            [....] //This is where the details of the vehicle are generated.
        }
        this.agrotime = RandomGeneration.GetRandomTime224(rn1);
        this.vExists = true;
        this.serviced = false;
        //agroTimeHandler = new AgrivationHandler(agrotime);
        agroTimer.Interval = agrotime;
        agroTimer.Elapsed += AgroTimerElapsed;
        agroTimer.Start();
    }

    public static void AgroTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here is where I need to set vExists to "False"
    }
}
```

However I need to generate a specific instance of the class as far as I'm aware to do that, because it doesn't like "this.vExists = false", it just errors.

Comment: You should try to write code and post it here (see [MCVE] for guidance). Trying anything else (jumping, singing, running) not going to help and definitely does not make post good SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible.
Try the following:

```
private void LoadTimer()
   Timer timer = new Timer
   timer.Interval = 4000;
   timer.Enabled = true; 
   timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
   timer.Start(); 
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do your boolean operation where
}
```